# Options for file backed persistence in Java and Spring

Tags: java, spring, file-io, persistent-storage

I am inexperienced with Spring and I've been reading up on persistence options in Spring, as I am trying to find a suitable way to store data without the use of a database such as Oracle or MySQL etc...

When my app loads, it will read a file containing IDs. As the app runs, it may gain new IDs which will need to be written to the file in case of a crash. From what I can tell, I will need to replace the whole file each time, which is fine, as the data should be held in RAM and I can just overwrite the original file.

What I would prefer, however, is a way in Spring, or even Java, to sync the file and the data so that if I add 1 new ID to my list, it would automatically add a single line to the end of the file without me needing to write additional file management code. I know I can probably just concatenate the line, but something that basic probably won't be thread safe, and thread safety is a major concern here. I'd rather find a ready-made lib rather than re-invent the wheel.

So, can anyone point me in the direction of a tutorial, or technology, that allows for what I need? Or tell me if one exists, or how best I should go about this?

Thanks.

EDIT: It seems Springs resource bundle is the way forward. But I don't think it does exactly what I need to do. Using this, I will have to write code to both add to the map, and then add to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look of [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)

Is a thread safe and server less sql database with Java driver.

**EDIT**

Other option is spring batch support for flat files.

see http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#flatfiles

Comment: Hi, unfortunately we can't use a database of any kind. It has to be a text file. I'm looking at Springs resource bundle for an answer.